# Getting a range of bits from byte array

Tags: java, arrays, byte, bit-shift

I want to get a specific range of bits from the byte array { 0b00000001, 0b00100011, 0b00010001} and convert it into another byte array. For example from 5th bit till the 12th from left to right.
The result would look like this byte array { 0b00010010}. 
Unfortunately I couldnt find a faster option then reading the bits one by one and append them to a string builder until 8 and then put it into the array. 
Hopefully someone can solve this, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using left and right shift operations. These will convert the bytes into integers, so they need to be cast back to byte.

Below is a basic example. I use indexes starting at 0, so to test you example you would call rangeOf(sourceByteArray, 4, 11). This function only demonstrates the method; checking should be done on the ranges and it can probably be made faster.

```
public byte[] rangeOf(byte[] source, int start, int end){
        int firstSourceByte = start/8;
        int shift = start%8;
        int size = (end - start)/8;
        if ((end - start)%8>0) size++;
        byte[] returnArray = new byte[size];

        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            returnArray[i] = (byte) (source[firstSourceByte + i] << shift);
            returnArray[i] += (byte) (source[firstSourceByte + i +1] >> (8 - shift));
        }

        return returnArray;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately your method could only solve every second byte correct, don't know why :D
I tested it with this byte array from start = 12 and end = 48.

byte [] s = {(byte)0b01000000,(byte) 0b00000000, (byte)0b00010011,(byte) 0b00010000, (byte)0b11101100,(byte) 0b00010001,(byte) 0b11101100, (byte)0b00010001, (byte)0b11101100, (byte)0b00010001}

The Result was like this:

00000001
00110001
11111110  <- this doesn't work
11000001
00001110

I found another solution with BigInteger using rightShift and leftShift until this bits are in right position to read it directly from the byte array. 
Thanks for your help!